# How to make an exact loop cut on an oblique edge?

Tags: modeling

I did stand for my model, and I want to do support edges on 3mm at all faces. I did this everywhere by this method: I press ctrl + R, created loop cut, bring it to the end of the face and then move it, like G + X + 3mm. When I got the last loop cut, I faced a problem: I cant move loop cut on Z axis, because face is oblique. I looked for how I can solve this, maybe move loop cut not on the Z axis, but move on normal axis. I hope you understand, there are model and picture, where I did what I want, but I need exactly straight cut.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You mean like loop-slide (G+G)?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Yes, somethig like this, but size, not percent moving

Comment: Hello :). Perhaps the Bevel tool could work. With two segments and profile=1 it will create two loops around selected edge. Bevel allows absolute values (mm) unlike loopcuts.

Comment: @JachymMichal this created angle and did loops at both sides, it does not work

Comment: @user99579 It does work, I use it all the time for precise loops. Perhaps you missed a step :).

Comment: @JachymMichal Ah, I did this again, you are rigth. Thanks, it is one of solves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved:

1. Subdivide edge one time.
2. With Edit Mesh Tools add-on set edge length (before this you need to apply scale by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>> Apply> Apply all transforms or (in 3d Viewport) *Object> Apply> Apply* all transforms).
3. Switch to any orthographic view (top, bottom, left or other) and extrude vertex by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and enabled (in 3d Viewport in Edit Mode) *Options> Auto Merge> Split Edges* and faces (on top).
4. Do this with all sides, removing duplicates if needed. You can check edge length by using *Overlays> Measurement> Edge Length* (in the 3D Viewport).

You can do the same thing with the Knife tool, but the Knife won't work in all situations.

Also, one of the ways:
Bevel edges with settings: segments - 2, profile - 1. Bevel has differrent modes (Offset, Width and other), we need Offset. For bevel modifier you can do vertex groups where you need and bevel just them.